# Make filter dropdown menus move into heading - VBA Excel 2016

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

When scrolling down, row 1 should replace the letters in the heading, but with my code it just disappears like a normal row.
How do I have to change my code in order to get this result?:

[image] [image]

(Default Excel 2016 CSV import)

**Existing Code:**

`With ActiveSheet
    .Range("A1:" & Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address).AutoFilter
End With`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is creating a table (*Insert -> Tables -> Table*) and select "My Table has headers"

[Guide on support.office.com](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-an-Excel-table-e81aa349-b006-4f8a-9806-5af9df0ac664)

Answer (score 0):

you want to hide headings

it is in the ribbon ... view ... show ... headings

vba code

```
    ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = False
```

then split and freeze top row

record a macro of the action if you need code